# How to create provable burn address containing specific words?

Tags: address, hash, burn

I'd like to Burn a portion of the Tezos Till We Bezos token supply to a MacKenzie themed address in keeping with the meme https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2019/jun/30/amazon-jeff-bezos-ex-wife-mackenzie-handed-38bn-in-divorce-settlement

I noted Arthur B  was able to generate such an address "tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX"  here:  [How can I make a proof of burn address?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/how-can-i-make-a-proof-of-burn-address)

How do I do this?  Or could someone generate one with MacKenzie in the address
eg: tz1MacKenzieburnburnburnburnbujAYjjX

I tried that,  but the address is not valid,  it needs the correct ending to make it a valid address and I am unsure how to go about doing this

Comment: Have a look at this agora post: [Canonical burn](https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/canonical-burn/2653/1)

Comment: As was suggested in the comments of the deleted answer, the easiest way to have a provable burn is to send the tez or the fa1.2/fa2 tokens to a smart contract that has no capability to send them out.

Comment: Yes,  I could so that using the Crunchy Firepit.   But it does not have the Panche fitting Tezos Till We Bezos.                     If  ArthurB was able to generate a valid address consisting mostly of the word "burn"   then there's the possibility of replacing some "burn"   with MacKenzie,    the woman who Divorced from Jeff Bezos...

Comment: Are you telling me that no one on the whole of stack exchange knows the dark magic that was used to create     tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX  ?